# Is it dangerous to post your Apple Dev team identifier online?

Tags: security, code-signing, entitlements

I'm working on code using XPC for inter-process communication. Sharing the code on GitHub will expose the `.entitlements` file, containing my team identifier.

Now will this be a security risk in any way?

Other developers could use the team identifier but won't be able to *sign* apps. So I expect everythings okay as long as I sandbox and sign my apps and helpers. What do you know about this?

Answer (score 1):

It probably won't be a huge security risk, however to be sure and to keep your git repository clean I suggest adding it to your gitignore file. There is no reason why you would need to share your .entitlements file.

Comment: Wouldn't others need to replicate the sandbox settings if they were to follow along?